# Enforcing variable declaration for a subclass in php

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, phpunit

I have an abstract class like this

```
<?php
    abstract class AbastractCreationCommand extends AbstactCommand {
        protected $repository;
        function handle($payload) {
            $this->repository->create($payload);
        }
    }

    class TagCreationCmd extends AbstractCreationCommand {
        function __constructor() {
            $this->repository = new TagRepository();
        }
    }
?>
```

**Questions**:

- is there a way I could enforce the definition of the repository class  in the subclasseses of the `AbstractCreationCommand` ?
- Do I need to create a test for each subclass and call `handle` method or is another way to test all my code?

Answer (score 1):

1.Yes. I do the same when I need to force instantiation of some dependancies. And this way is support [GRASP: Creator principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_(object-oriented_design)#Creator).

Another way to accomplish that with dependency injection, but this way broke Creator principle:

```
class TagCreationCmd extends AbstractCreationCommand {
    function __constructor(TagRepositoryInterface $tagRepository) {
        $this->repository = $tagRepository;
   }
}
```

2. If follow [3 rules of TDD](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.TheThreeRulesOfTdd) you should write test for each line of code. So the answer is yes.

Answer (score 1):

Answering number 1: You cannot enforce the creation of anything in subclasses from within your abstract class. At least not during instantiation. Everything in the subclass is optional.

However, your code in the abstract class could check whether or not the necessary objects have been defined when executing the part of the code that needs it, like this:

```
abstract class AbastractCreationCommand extends AbstactCommand {
    protected $repository;
    function handle($payload) {
        if (!$this->repository instanceof TagRepository) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Need a TagRepository');
        }
        $this->repository->create($payload);
    }
}
```

However, is likely doing the complaining too late. And the reason may be because you are using inheritance instead of composition, or are inheriting the wrong things.

First of all, you are not doing dependency injection. Your subclass should not directly instantiate that TagRepository. This leads to problems testing your abstract class' code, as well as the subclass code, because you cannot provide a mock object instead. This severely limits the ability to test your code in isolation.

Also, the subclass cannot work without knowing very specifically how to inherit the abstract class beyond implementing any abstract functions. If both abstract and subclass come from you as the author, I would consider it to be ok to impose doing all things correctly on you. But if you expect other developers to inherit that abstract class (and your question sounds like this might be the background problem), then you shouldn't do this at all.

Abstract classes do provide some common functions to a set of subclasses through inheritance. But the same thing could be achieved if you put all the code into a non-abstract class and inject this class into independent ex-sub classes. They will call these common functions as public methods instead of private or protected, and the testing of the common code is also easier, because the methods are public.

Also note that you already have three levels of inheritance, which is nearing a uncomfortable level: AbstractCommand -> AbstractCreationCommand -> TagCreationCmd.

The problem is that everything you change in AbstractCommand has to be done with two levels of inheriting objects in mind. You cannot simply change a protected variable's name. You cannot simply add a protected (or public) variable without checking if any of the sub classes already has such a variable with the same name - unless you intend to share it.

The problems with maintaining code that is inherited is not with the classes at the end of the inheritance chain, but with these at the top. Just think about how many classes might be affected with different usage contexts: If you have AbstractCreationCommands, you will have AbstractDeletionCommands and AbstractChangeCommands and AbstractDoNothingCommands, and a plethora of concrete commands of all these kinds doing plenty of different stuff. Just imaging that on each level, you have four classes - this makes you having to maintain one base class, four inheriting classes, and four times four concrete classes - for a whopping 21 classes in total, all of them having to be tested, and likely none of them gaining any benefit from being an `instanceof AbstractCommand`.

Answering number 2: Yes, you have to test all subclasses - these are the ones that get instantiated and used. You should also test the abstract class' code in isolation. PHPUnit offers to instantiate an abstract class with the mock framework, so any abstract method would be mocked and could be configured. However, I always have a bad feeling when I use a mock as the real tested object because I am not really testing the pure code, but some combination of mock code and real code.

A possible way out is to create a test class that barely does anything beyond extending the abstract class, and work with this one.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way I could enforce the definition of the repository class in the subclasseses of the AbstractCreationCommand ?

I don't see the necessity tbh. If your `AbstractCreationCommand` needs a repo to work, add it as a constructor param. This doesn't *enforce* the repo to be injected because a subtype can override the constructor, but it should be abundantly clear that an `AbstractCreationCommand` subtype requires some sort of repo then, e.g.

```
abstract class AbstractCreationCommand extends AbstractCommand 
{
    private $repository;

    public function __construct(Repository $repository) 
    {
        $this->repository = $repository
    }

    protected function getRepository(): Repository 
    {
        return $this->repository;
    }

    // …
```

You could also use a *Template Method* pattern to indicate that any subtype will utilize a repo by adding an abstract getter for the repo. The subtype will have to implement that method then. It's then up to the developer to decide on the implementation:

```
abstract class AbstractCreationCommand extends AbstractCommand
{
    public function handle()
    {
        $this->getRepository()->create();
    }

    abstract function getRepository(): Repository;

    // …
```

If you really must *enforce* it at creation level, you can set the abstract type's constructor to `final protected` and do any subtype creation in a static factory method, e.g.

```
abstract class AbstractCreationCommand extends AbstractCommand
{
    private $repository;

    final protected function __construct(Repository $repository)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }

    // …
```

This now prevents direct instantiation of any subtypes via `new`. Trying to `new` a subtype, will result in PHP Fatal error.

Instead the subtype must be created like this:

```
class TagCreationCommand extends AbstractCreationCommand
{
    private $foo;

    public static function create(Repository $repository, Foo $foo)
    {
        $command = new static ($repository);
        $command->setFoo($foo);

        return $command;
    }

    protected function setFoo(Foo $foo)
    {
        $this->foo = $foo;
    }

    // …
```

Then you'd call `TagCreationCommand::create(new TagRepository, new Foo);` to get a new instance. Since you cannot override the constructor and have to call the parent constructor from within the static `create` method, you effectively enforce a `Repository` now to be there. I added the Foo stuff only to illustrate how you'd use additional dependencies.

As you can hopefully see, this requires quite a lot of gymnastics compared to the much more lightweight previous two approaches that will basically result in the same outcome. After all, if there is no repo, the code will fail. And since you are using tests, this will get noticed. So why bother?

> Do I need to create a test for each subclass and call handle method or is another way to test all my code?

If you are overriding the `handle` method, you should test that behavior in a concrete test class for that subtype.

If your subtypes *do not* override the `handle` method, you can create an `AbstractCreationCommandTest` and put a test for the `handle` method in there. However, if that is the case, I wonder why you need the `AbstractCreationCommand` to be abstract in the first place because then it sounds like you just need a `CreationCommand`.

Answer (score -1):

Following Yan Burtovoy's suggestion, I would go even further and actually enforce a [DI container](http://php-di.org/)

```
<?php
abstract class AbastractCreationCommand extends AbstactCommand {
    protected $repository;
    function __constructor(\DI\Container $container) {
        $this->repository = $container->get('TagRepository');
    }

    function handle($payload) {
        $this->repository->create($payload);
    }
}
```

You should create tests for everything that is exposed to users of your library (that would be your application).
So, if you have a subclass that relies on `handle()` being called then you should write a test for that. Reason being that in 6 months someone might change the inheritance or overwrite the `handle()` method and change the initial expected behaviour.

Comment: I get somehow your point. I do not see why I need to test handle method in each subclass as there is no code that needs to be covered. If someone ads a overwrite of the method handle, it generates new code without test code coverage so it has to write a new test.

Comment: I would say that, as a developer, you have to make sure your tests cover the 'published' functionality of the code. The new developer 'has' to write a test but he might not and the result is that *your* application stops working.  
By providing tests for each implementation you make sure you cover all the use cases. It's more about how *you finish your job* rather than how others do theirs :). In the end, this fictional reckless developer might not even run the tests at all.

Comment: Never inject the DI container anywhere. Google the "service locator antipattern" for plenty of reasons why it actually is a very bad idea. It makes testing a pain, btw.